# iOS borders on top and bottom of the screen with React Native, Expo Router and Stack screens

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo, tailwind-css

This is my first project with React Native and Expo, so forgive me if there is something out of place, but I can't figure it out how to fix this issue.

I'm using React Native, Expo and Expo Router. In the current state, I have App.js that it's just a bunch of buttons that leads to other screens for testing purposes. My current app-folder structure is like this (please ignore the test file):

[image: App folder file structure]

The layout for the User is meant to show a personalized Header, with a profile picture on the right, an image on the center and actions button on the right. User screens should navigate back and forth between screens, so I have made this layout inside the user folder:

```
export default function UserHeaderBar() {
return (
        <Stack
                screenOptions = {{
                    headerTransparent: Platform.OS !== 'android',
                    headerBlurEffect: "light",
                    headerBackVisible: true,
                    headerBackTitleVisible: false,
                    headerTitleAlign: "center",
                    headerTitle: props => <CompanyLogo/>,
                    headerLeft: props => <UserAvatar />,
                    headerRight: props => <ActionButtons/>
                }}>
        </Stack>
);
```

}

This is working just fine on Android (I have painted in blue the index content to better see the issue, avatar and logo has been blurred by me for privacy purposes):

[image: Header on Android]

However, I'm facing issues on iOS. As you can see, the Header is supposed to be transparent, and it should blur the content behind. But it seems there is a weird padding to avoid the notch and the gesture bar of iOS. Here is the top on iOS, with the white space on top of the header bar instead of it blending with the rest:

[image: iOS top]

And the bottom (notice the white space where instead it should be blue):

[image: iOS bottom]

My index page is quite simple:

```
export default function UserPage() {

return (
       <SafeAreaView style={tw`flex-1 flex-row justify-center bg-blue-700`}>
                <StatusBar style={"dark"} />
                <ScrollView style={tw`w-full`}>
                     // content
                </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>
)
```

}

And App.js is basically the default one:

```
    export default function App() {
  useDeviceContext(tw);
  return (
        <SafeAreaProvider style={styles.container}>
            <NavigationContainer>
                  <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
                  <StatusBar style="auto" />
            </NavigationContainer>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}
```

I'm also using twrnc to style some components using Tailwind. What should I change to "blend" my content with the top and bottom bar on iOS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Safe Area View acts differently on android and iOS if you want to get rid of that you have to check what device your user uses and according to that if its iOS render in View and if its android you can render in SafeAreView

Comment: With "View" setted in my layout (user) I actually have content that goes behind the translucent header, but I still have white borders on top and bottom. Also, the content begins under the header when headerTransparent is true, while the content starts as normal when headerTransparent is false.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing this issue and I think the problem is lack of configuring expo-router because in documentation when we [install](https://docs.expo.dev/router/installation/#install-dependencies) expo-router
it has a react-native-safe-area-context in list of packages that means expo router has a built in SafeAreaView or SafeAreaProvider there should be some configuration to get rid of notches.